# rqrcode on ruby rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried the example in this website:

https://richonrails.com/articles/generating-qr-codes-in-your-ruby-on-rails-application

to generate a qr code.  there seems to be a problem with the require 'rqrcode' line which I have in the config/environment.rb file.

I checked that the gem is installed and it is.  I removed the line require 'rqrcode' from the config/environment.rb file and then I get error 'uninitialized constant QrCodesController::RQRCode'  at the controller:

```
 def create
    @qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(qr_code_params[:text],size:4)
 end
```

when I re-add the line require 'rqrcode' and restart the rails server, I get the error - 'require': cannot load such file - rqrcode (LoadError).

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Based on the link you provided, your require line should be `require 'rqrcode'` (without the hyphen).

Comment: sorry, i did a mistake on my post.  i do have it as as require 'rqrcode', however i am still getting the error.  i updated the post. thanks!

Comment: If you have it in your gemfile you dont need to require it.

Comment: @GorillaApe yes, however when I remove it then I get an error  'uninitialized constant QrCodesController::RQRCode' at the controller:               def create
    qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(qr_code_params[:text],size:4)
 end  thanks for replying!

Comment: could you try @qr = ::RQRCode::QRCode.new(....)